# Quest for Glory 3 honey issues

Tags: dosbox, quest-for-glory-3

I'm playing Quest for Glory 3 (fully patched) in Dosbox but I'm a bit stuck.

I discovered the location with the bees but had no honey at that stage. I left and the bee map marker appeared on my map. I now have the honey but I don't seem able to return to the bees.

Returning to the map marker seems to lead to a generic savannah screen and trying to use the honey on the ground has no effect.

I'm not sure if there's a specific pixel on that map marker I need to click or if I only had one chance to use the honey, when first discovering the bees.

Comment: I've added the tag for the Game, but you do have the create tag privilege as an fyi!

Comment: Appreciated! I assumed that I didn't but should have just tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to hit the map marker from the North side! South side won't work. Turns out this is only for healing items anyway - not needed for dispel potion.